# Module initialization error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using **virtualenv** and **serverless-python-requirements** for my Python deployment in **AWS Lambda** using the serverless framework. But after upload when I am calling the function it is giving **“module initialization error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument”** error.

I am new to the serverless framework so couldn't find out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my serverless.yml file https://gist.github.com/himadriganguly/f9571c09a3c01c79ebf920034f5e5e55

Comment: Can you share your serverless.yml file?

Comment: @tkwargs Edited my post and added the serverless.yml file link. Thank you.

Comment: I ran into something similar when trying with python 3.6 runtime. I ended up switching to 2.7 and everything worked fine.  Check the [docs](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#updating-to-python-36) on using Python 3.6. Also (in case you haven't already), verify you're in a virtualenv running Python 3.6 when deploying. Let us know if that helps!

Comment: Already running Python 3.6.2 under virtualenv.

Comment: Do think that there is any issue with Python 3.6 on AWS Lambda as before using serverless when I am packaging it manually to create a zip file and uploading it to Lambda it is working fine.

Comment: It's hard to say without some thorough testing.  One way to check is to try and deploy under python 2.7 and see if you get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error is fixed now, it is the serverless framework issue.

They have fixed it on 1.21.1 release.

(https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.21.1).